# Angular - Reactive form, how to correctly store the initial value, and check for changes in the form?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using reactive forms with angular 6 and I have 2 questions.

First one, what's the correct way to store the initial value of a form?

I'm pretty new to angular, and what I've done so far, is to declare in the controller all the form code, and then in the view I bind those controls with the `fromControlName` tag.

Everything works correctly, but now I want to implement a Save/Cancel button.
As the form comes prefilled based on some choices made by the user (I prefill the form with `this.myForm.get("valueToPrefill").setValue(prefillValue)`) so when the user opens the form, some fields will be already prefilled!

What I need to do, is, to clone somehow or store the initial data, so when the user is done editing, if he presses "Save", then this temporary form data will be written on the form (I guess with the same way I prefill it, `get("form_Name).setValue(`) right?), but if he were to use the Cancel button, then I should revert to form to the original state!

Currently when an user fills a form value, it gets written directly on the form, because of the `fromControlName` tag, which binds the input fields to my form.

What should I do here to have a copy of the form to write on, and only after I save, it writes those value on the original form I declared in my controller?

Second question, currently my Save button gets disabled if the form is pristine.
But I would want to go one step further! 
If a user deletes a characted, or changes a dropdown, but then reverts those changes by going back to the original value, the form is now dirty, but the data actually never changed from the initial status! So how can keep the Save button disabled in this case?
I can imagine doing a check when I manage to have a cloned form, so I can check the initial data with the stored one, and compare them right?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try first then come with specific questions if you struggle ! You can find a very nice tutorial, I even googled one for you : https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-reactive-forms-tutorial/

Comment: thank you, my specific question is mostly on how to check if a field of my form has not changed (pristine/dirty is not enough), so if a user changes something, but then changes it back before saving the form, the Save button should be disabled because the form is the same as before!

Comment: If you create a stackblitz project, I'll be glad to show you a way to implement what you want

Comment: is there around a premade stackblitz with just formGroups? as my form is huge with lots of validators and it would be painful to put it on stackblitz! One field would be more than enough to just understand the logic on how to check if the value has really changed! Gonna quickly look for a premade stackblitz with formGroup

Comment: here a stackblizt with a single formgroup and a formArray, and a save button that for now is disabled when the form is pristine

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout-hriofz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Do you work with material component ? If no, I will check for another stackblitz or create one

Comment: yes, I work with material and I made that stackblitz with parts of my big reactive form!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186450/discussion-between-florian-and-aj989).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout-d2qc5b)
You don't need to have a copy of the form because you have your original data.
You need to identify your data, currently you only have `grade` and `value` which are two fields in the form. So I added an id to identify your pairs.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use the @angular/forms API for that (https://angular.io/api/forms):

```
saveForm(){
this.savedFormState = formGroup.getRawValue()
}
resetForm(){
formGroup.patchValue(this.saveFormState);
// Reset states like dirty, markAsTouched
}
```

Note that the object has to match with your FormGroup.

Comment: thank you for the answer, for resetting the form, that is clear and I'm doing it, but I didn't quite get your saveForm(), what does getRawValue() retrieve? The current state and values of each field of my FormGroup?  So if that's the case, I should save the RawValue onto a Var when the form is initialized, to have a copy of the initial form?   So getRawValue() is always my current form, and savedFormState is the form in the last state it has been saved?

Comment: Yes getRawValue() returns an objects with the same structure as your AbstractControl.

You Can store this data in a variable and use it when you need it.